# Get folder path from file with pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, substring, filenames, series

I am using pandas to work on a list of filepaths and I need to extract the folder path.

So from:

```
/volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/FILE.TXT
/volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/FILE.PDF
```

I need to get the folder path:

```
/volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/
/volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/
```

I have found a way to get the file name but not the folder path

```
data['index'] = data['File'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and extract the first split, via either a list comprehension or `apply` with a custom function.

```
from os.path import splitext

df = pd.DataFrame({'filepaths': [r'/volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/FILE.TXT',
                                 r'/volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/FILE.PDF']})

# list comprehension, more efficient
df['folder'] = [splitext(x)[0] for x in df['filepaths']]

# apply + lambda implicit loop
df['folder'] = df['filepaths'].apply(lambda x: splitext(x)[0])

print(df)

                                 filepaths  \
0            /volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/FILE.TXT   
1  /volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/FILE.PDF   

                                folder  
0            /volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/FILE  
1  /volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/FILE
```

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
data['index'] = data['File'].str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[0] + '/'
```

If no missing values and performance is important:

```
data['index'] = [x.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/' for x in data['File']]


print (data)
                                      File                            index
0            /volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/FILE.TXT            /volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/
1  /volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/FILE.PDF  /volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pandas-path`](https://github.com/drivendataorg/pandas-path/) library wraps pathlib as a `.path` accessor on any pandas series or index. That functionality makes this case pretty easy:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas_path import path

files = pd.Series([
    '/volume1/SYN/FOLDER1/FILE.TXT',
    '/volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER/FILE.PDF',
])

# .path accessor created by importing pandas_path
files.path.parent

#> 0              /volume1/SYN/FOLDER1
#> 1    /volume1/SYN/FOLDER2/SUBFOLDER
#> dtype: object
```

<sup>Created at 2021-03-06 22:21:15 PST by [reprexlite](https://github.com/jayqi/reprexlite) v0.4.2</sup>